# php function output in a table row... how?

Tags: php, html, function, html-table

I want to run this function but show the result in a table row:

```
strlen($cat_row['sms']
```

This is what I came up with but it is not working:

```
echo  `"<tr><td bgcolor=#626E7A>".**strlen($cat_row['cars']**."</td></tr>";`
```

How do you show result of a php function in a table row? I am trying to format the output somehow.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

No need for `**`, try this instead:

```
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#626E7A>" . strlen($cat_row['cars']) . "</td></tr>";
```

The concatenation operator in php is a dot (`.`).

Comment: I think he was trying to make it **bold** although it isn't possible inside code :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing a closing parenthesis:

```
echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#626E7A">' . strlen($cat_row['cars']) . '</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work, but you have to make sure that you close the brackets for the function:

Your code:

```
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#626E7A>".strlen($cat_row['cars']."</td></tr>";
```

Corrected code:

```
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#626E7A>".strlen( $cat_row['cars'] )."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple problem with a simple solution:

```
<tr><td bgcolor=#626E7A><?php echo strlen($cat_row['cars']; ?></td></tr>
```

Hopefully that will work for you!